# How to find common words in two columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am stuck with a task which am seeking help from you guys. the solution I want is to find common words in two columns. eg if a word comes common in two cells it must appear in another column. we don't need the words only in one column.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u_AD1FAbq0ntushGSYZBsR59iPX1_p5ZSIq1mowQSQ4/edit#gid=0

pls take a look to the shared link.

A screenshot also is shown here:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a array context,

- `MATCH` Col1  against Col2 getting indexes of strings in Col1 that are present in Col2
- `FILTER` Col1 against the resulting matched array

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(A2:A10,MATCH(A2:A10,B2:B10,0)))
  ```

Comment: As a way to complete this answer here are the references for these three functions : [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) , [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) and [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en). Also note that ```FILTER``` will return the value of the cells in the range that met the specified conditions (in this case the indexes from ```MATCH```).